# Postgres CSV UTF8 encoding problem åäö (Python)

Tags: python, database, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I am having an encoding problem with Postgres when importing a CSV file.

I have created a database in Postgres and created all the data I want in a csv file. My database client and server encoding is UTF8 and I saved the file as UTF8. I´ve tried saving it in different editors like Excel, Apache Open Office, NotePad++ all in UTF8, but I import it to Postgres using \COPY statement the Swedish characters åäö won't work and are showing ├Ñ, ├ñ,├Â and other characters as well.

I guess it is an encoding problem but as I know my database is in UTF8 and the CSV file the same, and what´s really frustrating is that it worked the other day and I am 99% sure I did the same thing...

I managed to get around the letters in the database using

```
UPDATE places SET description = replace(description, '├Ñ', 'å');
```

However them I connect to the database using psycopg2 in Python the characters are showing like ”, † etc even though Python encoding is UTF8 as well. But really I want to fix it in the database and not go around it like this.

It seems to be an issue when the file is being imported to Postgres but I feel like I´ve tried everything.. Any ideas?

Comment: I had no problem loading those characters using \copy (Once I figured out how to get them pasted into a file using my terminal program.)  Can you show the simplest version of the python script you used?

Comment: I want to get it right in the database like with right encoding because then Python will show the characters correctly(at least when I tried it and succeeded the other day). I only use Python to store it in a list for display (its a basic app). How did you do it?  
Arriesjön-Risebjär- This is what I want,
Arriesj├Ân-Risebj├ñr- This is what shows in the database once I´ve imported the file using \copy and saving it as utf8,
Arriesj”n-Risebj„r - this is what Python shows me when I do a "select" query from the database and save it in a list and print it.
I am new to both Python and databases.

Comment: I just pasted your title into Windows notepad, saved it as a utf8 encoded file, then sent it to Linux where I set the client_encoding to utf8 and did the \copy.  Are you sure it is not correct in the database?  Could it be that python is reading it correctly from the database, and spitting it out correctly as utf8 to the terminal, but your terminal is interpreting it as something other than utf8 and so displaying it wrong?

Comment: I solved it! I had to put in this before i connected to the database, dont know why...
SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8
chcp 65001